# WinRT creating 'Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog' in a Desktop app fails

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, desktop, abi

Any ideas why is the above code failing to create an class instance. I'm trying to use WinRT in a Windows Application and here is the code snippet, it fails where is commented with '!':

```
#include <Roapi.h>
#include <Winstring.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windows.ui.popups.h>
#include <windows.foundation.h>

inline void CheckHresult(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DebugBreak();
    }
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    CheckHresult(RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED));

    static const wchar_t ClassName[] = L"Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog";

    HSTRING hClassStr, hStr;

    CheckHresult(WindowsCreateString(ClassName, sizeof(ClassName) / sizeof(ClassName[0]) - 1, &hClassStr));

    ABI::Windows::UI::Popups::IMessageDialog* pClass;
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    CheckHresult(RoActivateInstance(hClassStr, (IInspectable**)&pClass)); //here it fails with E_NOTIMPL !!!!!!!!!!

    WindowsDeleteString(hClassStr);

    static const wchar_t msgTitleName [] = L"Metro Message Box!";

    CheckHresult(WindowsCreateString(msgTitleName, sizeof(msgTitleName) / sizeof(msgTitleName[0]) - 1, &hStr));

    CheckHresult(pClass->put_Title(hStr));

    WindowsDeleteString(hStr);

    static const wchar_t msgContent [] = L"Hello Metro.";

    CheckHresult(WindowsCreateString(msgContent, sizeof(msgContent) / sizeof(msgContent[0]) - 1, &hStr));

    CheckHresult(pClass->put_Content(hStr));

    WindowsDeleteString(hStr);

    CheckHresult(pClass->ShowAsync(nullptr));
}
```

I have no idea why this happens.'

EDIT:

The 'RoActivateInstance' function fails trying to activate the instance of class named ['Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) with HRESULT of 'E_NOTIMPL'.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom of the MSDN page you linked to, it says Minimum Supported Client is Windows 8 **Store apps** only.

The API is not supported in a normal desktop program.